# Weekly drive idea: system agnostic

Tags: discussion, questions

Would you be interested in running a week *system agnostic* drive?  I am happy to give away some reputation for good questions/answers. The aim would be to broaden the site to include more questions about role playing in general instead of the heavy D&D rules ones.

Good idea?

Bad idea?

Comment: What would we be doing to make it happen? My initial answer is "sure, if there's a plan for an effective one."

Comment: @mxyzplk: How about a contest?  Other ideas welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I'd much rather see one of the concrete tags like gm-techniques, roleplaying, or campaign-development highlighted. Those tags tend to create non-rules questions naturally, and are a bit more cohesive.

System-agnostic has a lot of issues: A case could be made that a lot of system-tagged questions should also be tagged system-agnostic, and a lot of people already strip out a lot of important information from their question to create a "pure" system agnostic question. Incentivizing people to break the tag seems like a bad idea.

Comment: System-agnostic, as far as I understand the term, should be use for rules advice that could be applied to any system or no system at all.  If you are asking about some D&D $keyword, then you should tag it as D&D. On the other hand, if you are asking about erosion of metals (for armours and weapons) in desert climate, then it should be tagged system agnostic.  Does that makes sense?

Comment: @Sardathrion I don't really want to see the site overrun with questions about the erosion of metals in a desert climate. Those questions are tolerable, but they're not really great *rpg* questions.

Comment: @Sardathrion For a question that straddles the SA-on-system-tagged issue see here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3601/77 . That question received an objectively great system-agnostic answer (even if it WAS my own answer). Should it be tagged system-agnostic?

Comment: Yes, I think the above question could be tagged system-agnostic since the poster asks for out of system information -- Both Trail of Cthulhu and Call of Cthulhu but not restrictive to either.  Maybe we need to define what the term means? To me, it *should mean* that answers which are not system specific (either different system(s) or systemless or generic advise) are sought after as well as system specific answers. Does that make sense?

Comment: One a side note, I would be **much more** interested in an *What is the erosion of metals in a desert climate?* question than an *Does Smell carry through deprecated zones in water when a Monk uses Nose Power on a Fish?*...  And before you ask, yes, that is what most D&D4e questions sound like to me.  ^_~  </FireProofArmour::ON>

Comment: @Sardathrion "*it should mean that answers which are not system specific (either different system(s) or systemless or generic advise) are sought after as well as system specific answers.*" This is the way things should be **all the time**. If I ask a question about my 7th Sea game, and you have a non-rules answer that works, you should post it. I shouldn't have to have a tag that says "no, really, I want my question answered."

Comment: @Sardathrion But besides that, it gets into the whole **what does system-agnostic really mean?** issue. Is it questions that can be answered either rules or non-rules? Is it questions that are strictly non-rules? Is it historical/physical arcana? If we have a contest on a tag we want it to be as clear as possible about what's in and out of the tag.

Comment: @Sardathrion *"I would be much more interested in..."* Okay. Personally, I'm more interested in "How do I make a million dollars over the weekend" than either, but I don't think that's appropriate here :) For the record, a lot of the 4e rules questions aren't great questions either.

Comment: Agree... Shall you ask the *what does system-agnostic really mean?* question on meta or shall I?

Comment: @Sardathrion There's already been quite a lot of talk on Meta about what the system-agnostic tag does/doesn't mean. The gist of it is, that it means different things to different people, but is generally popular even in a nebulous state. Which is okay for a tag, but isn't great for a contest. Again, I'd recommend tags like gm-techniques and roleplaying as generating a high degree of questions that match your definition of system-agnostic.